# How to show the per-file history as the default Git panel in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I seem to have gotten into a mode for the *Intellij Git Tool* in which the default panel is the *Git Log* instead of the *Changes* view.

[image]

How can the *Git Tool* be reset to show the *Changes* view - which is the "factory default" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Version Control | Commit | Use non-modal commit interface.

Comment: Will accept in the requisite 10 mins.  btw is this a recent change?

Comment: This feature was introduced since 2020.1 public builds. It's enabled by default for the clean installations. If you import the existing settings from the previous versions, this option will be disabled by default.

Comment: Unsetting this actually changes another behavior: the diff's now go into the editor panel instead of the modal dialog.  I'm fine with that behavior so this is a perfect answer.

Comment: Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Advanced Settings | Open Diff as Editor Tab.